# Loop through severals objects js

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, for-in-loop

I want to retrieve data from an object, and I need to make several iterations. I have another object inside the first.

Here is what I try to do

```
for (var site in dataArray) {
    var itemList = site + ' - ' + dataArray[site].username + ' - ' + dataArray[site].followers + '<div class="detail"></div>' + '<br>';

    $('.test').append(itemList);

    for (var key in dataArray[site].details) {
        var itemDetail = ' - ' + key + ' ' + dataArray[site].details[key];

        $('.detail').append(itemDetail);
    }
}
```

But when I did this code, the first element append, receive all the key/value from the others details objects. I only want to display the details object related with his site parent site object.

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JeremDsgn/7EX6M/

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to iterate through the first object and after through the second object (details) but maybe I don't need the two for...in loop to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your selector `$('.detail')` selects **all** elements with class `detail`.

Try using the DOM instead of strings. I give you this as a personal advice. I used to append HTML via strings just like you're doing it now. Since I started using DOM objects as they are actually meant to be used, the javascript language became times more pleasant to work with.

```
for (var site in dataArray) {
    var itemList = site + ' - ' + dataArray[site].username + ' - ' + dataArray[site].followers;

    var details = document.createElement('div');
    details.className = 'detail';

    for (var key in dataArray[site].details) {
        var itemDetail = ' - ' + key + ' ' + dataArray[site].details[key];

        $(details).append(itemDetail);
    }

    $('.test').append(itemList).append(details);
}
```